# How can I enable the line numbers in the log query editor in Azure?

Tags: azure, numbers, line, azure-data-explorer, kql

How can I enable the line numbers in the log query editor in Azure?

I found [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/line-numbers-in-log-analytics-query-editor/) article. It states that the feature I am looking for indeed exists, but it does not tell how to enable it.

Comment: Check Azure Portal -> Log Analytics workspace -> Logs (Left-Hand menu) ->Setting (Top right Corner) -> Query Editor ->On (Show Row number in query editor)

Comment: @Naveen, how can I find the Log Analytics workspace to which my Application Insights belongs?

Comment: Application Insight -> Overview (Left Hand Panel) -> Workspace (Right Hand Panel) it will redirect you to the respective Log Analytics workspace
OR 
if you want to check and change the Workspace then Application Insight -> Properties(Left-Hand Panel) -> Workspace (Right-Hand Panel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps you can follow to enable line numbers in the azure log query editor.

> Check Azure Portal -> Log Analytics workspace -> Logs (Left-Hand menu)
> ->Setting (Top right Corner) -> Query Editor ->On (Show Row number in query editor)

1. Login to Azure Portal [Azure Portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/).
2. Navigate to Application Insights.
3. Select the Application Insights account for which you want to enable line numbers.
4. Select Logs
   [image: `]
5. Navigate to the Settings [image] icon in right most corner.
6. You can enable line number by using radio button highlighted below.[image]

To check respective workspace associated with given Application Insight.

> Application Insight -> Overview (Left Hand Panel) -> Workspace (Right
> Hand Panel) it will redirect you to the respective Log Analytics
> workspace OR if you want to check and change the Workspace then
> Application Insight -> Properties(Left-Hand Panel) -> Workspace
> (Right-Hand Panel)

[image]